# How to get only required xpath elements?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have an xml file that I want to store a node's rank attribute in a variable.

I tried:

```
echo $var = $xmlobj->xpath("//Listing[@rank]");
```

to no avail, it just prints **ArrayArray**.

How can this be done?

```
if($xmlobj = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($xml_feed)))
      {
            foreach($xmlobj as $listing)
            {

                  // echo 'Session ID: ' . $sessionId = $listing->sessionId . '<br />';
                  // echo 'Result Set: ' . $ResultSet = $listing->ResultSet . '<br />';

                  print_r($xmlobj->xpath("//Listing[@rank]"));

                  // $result = $xmlobj->xpath("/page/");
                  // print_r($result);

            }
      }
```

Henrik's suggestion:

```
foreach($xmlobj as $listing)
{
      $var = $xmlobj->xpath("//Listing[@rank]");

      foreach ($var as $xmlElement) 
      {
            echo (string)$xmlElement;
      }
}
```

Here you go

```
<page>
   <ResultSet id="adListings" numResults="3">
      <Listing rank="1" title="Reliable Local Moving Company" description="TEST." siteHost="www.example.com">
      </Listing>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit after playing around with the posted example xml:

- My initial answer was somewhat off track - casting to string would give you the *inner text* of the selected elements, if they have one (not the case here)
- `"//Listing[@rank]"` selects all 'Listing' Elements that *have* a 'rank' attribute. If you want to select the attributes themselves, use `"//Listing/@rank"`
- To output an attribute, use the SimpleXMLElement with array syntax: `$xmlElement['rank']`

So in your case:

```
foreach($xmlobj as $listing)
{
    $var = $xmlobj->xpath("//Listing/@rank");
    foreach ($var as $xmlElement) 
    {
      echo $xmlElement['rank'];
    }
}
```

or

```
foreach($xmlobj as $listing)
{
    $var = $xmlobj->xpath("//Listing[@rank]");
    foreach ($var as $xmlElement) 
    {
      echo $xmlElement['rank'];
      echo $xmlElement['title']; // Added to demonstrate difference
    }
}
```

should work.

In the first case, the $xmlElement would only contain the 'rank' attribute while in the second, it would contain the complete 'Listing' element (hence allowing the title output).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Henrik. Unfortunately it doesn't work, My implementation of your code is above?

Comment: Hmm, strange - what does it print?

Comment: Ok, that would hint on the xpath not actually matching anything - could you post an example of your xml?

Comment: Thanks for your help, posted above

Comment: Ok, took a while - I seem to have forgotten some basics since I last used simpleXML ;)

Comment: Henrik, thank you so much mate, that is perfect! - I appreciate all your help, all the best, Keith